# What is a rectangle of continuity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading my differential equations textbook and I've come across a concept I don't understand which is a "rectangle of continuity." Maybe this is just something that the authors of the textbook came up with. But here is an excerpt from the book for some context:

[image]

I understand the part about the requirements of the theorem, but I don't understand the purpose of the rectangle. Here is the picture of the 1.5 figure:

[image]

Could someone explain to me the importance of this "rectangle of continuity?" Is it useful for me to know?

Comment: It's just an odd way of saying that you are assuming continuity of $f$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ inside some rectangle.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Why is assuming that helpful?

Comment: It's something that will guarantee you that the conclusion of the theorem is true.